# Update zipcode to Pad with Zeros in SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a Zipcode column. 
The Zipcode column is an int.
How to I update this column to show padded zeros such that all values are 5 digits?
I know how to do this as a SELECT statement, but I don't know how to then update the coulmn in the table. Below is my best effort.

```
USE RTCA_new
GO

UPDATE tbl_BASE
SET Zipcode = (
SELECT FORMAT(Zipcode, '00000')
FROM rtca.tbl_BASE
               )
```

The resulting error is:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

In short, I would like a zipcode value 802 to display as 00802

Comment: Why do you want to store it with 0 paddings? Why not handle this when bringing back the data, in a stored proc, view, or even your application code?

Comment: I tried doing that but whenever I load it into SQL SERVER the data reverts to hiding the padded zeros :/

Comment: It is not possible to do what you want.   Your question stems from a fundamental misunderstanding of what an Integer is.

Comment: It sounds like you don't really want an INT for this column. What do you gain from having it as an integer?  You wouldn't do standard mathematical operations on that data... i.e. what's the sum of 4 users' zip codes?  This column is really a string data type not a numeric data type, so store it as a VARCHAR and your padding problems will go away. Use the answer provided by Luc to update your data after you've fixed your column type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've probably figured out, zip codes can start with 0.  `integers` in sql server do not allow for 0 padding.

I see your options as:

1. always padding it in the select
2. changing the column type to a more appropriate `varchar` and padding that with 0s up to 5 characters. (you should do this preferably)

Steps for new columns:

1. Create new `varchar(5)` column for `zipCode` (`newZipCode` as example)
2. populate the `newZipCode` column as:

   `update tbl_base 
   set newZipCode = right('00000' + cast(zipCode as varchar(5)), 5)`
3. drop your int `zipcode` column
4. rename your `newZipCode` column to `zipCode`

The specific reason for your error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

In the query:

```
UPDATE tbl_BASE
SET Zipcode = (
SELECT FORMAT(Zipcode, '00000')
FROM rtca.tbl_BASE
               )
```

Is because you have a logic error or similar in your statement. you're attempting to set a scalar value (ZipCode) to a set's value (your `select format...` statement.)

the statement:

```
SELECT FORMAT(Zipcode, '00000')
FROM rtca.tbl_BASE
```

by itself would return a row for every row in the table, you can't set a whole result set to a scalar value.  The immediate error can be fixed as so:

```
UPDATE tbl_BASE
SET Zipcode = FORMAT(Zipcode, '00000')
```

this would return a single value for zipcode... though again due to your current table schema, this would not give you the result you're hoping as `integer`s can't be padded with 0s

Comment: How would you update a varchar column to be padded if I were to cast the column as varchar?

Comment: @JasonMatney I'm not sure I understand your question... did my update help?

Comment: Yes, very much so. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

It works different:

```
Update tbl_BASE set zipcode = right('000000' + zipcode, 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to change the database design if possible (even though you might save a tiny bit of storage in the row by not using a string value.) If you do just need to convert it only for display purposes it's just a question of conversion.

```
select right('00000' + cast(zipcode as varchar(5)), 5) from T...
-- for use format() on later editions of SQL Server
```

By the way I would still recommend doing some reading about `update` to explore why you didn't really want a subquery for what you were trying to accomplish.

You could add a computed column to the table if you need this conversion to happen on the fly. Seeing that you were trying to update a column with a formatted value is probably evidence that the biggest problem was indeed a misunderstanding of data types as has already been pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your datatype for the `Zipcode` column to `varchar`. Once you do that, you could use `replicate`, `concat` and `right` functions to format your data:

```
UPDATE tbl_BASE
SET zipcode = right(CONCAT(
            replicate('0', 5)
            ,cast(zipcode as varchar(5))
            ), 5)
```